# Laravel - How routes interact with controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have this code:

`$app->get('myroute', ['uses' => 'MyController@method']);`

When i `http://app.com/myroute` it will create a new instance of MyController and calls `method()` or just calls the `method()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a new instance of `MyController` and then calls `method()` on it. You can test this by doing something like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    function __construct() {
        var_dump('__construct');
    }

    public function method() {
        var_dump('method()');
    }
}
```

That will result in a page that says:

```
__construct
method()
```

Which proves that's the order they go in. Additionally, you can (and are recommended in the docs) to use Dependency Injection via controller constructors where appropriate.